# MongoDB replica with Offline Database

Tags: mongodb

I would like to have Mongo on a server, then to replicate this onto a laptop.

The laptop is needed to leave the network and still be able to read/write, and once back on the network sync these changes with the primary.

At the same time I need the VM (Primary), to still be accessible (read/write).

So when each device is not talking to each other then for them to make themselves primary.

I have set up a very basic replica, Primary on a VM and the Secondary on the machine running the VM. In all examples I have seen it recommends having 3 servers for the replica, but I only need 2!

A couple of questions:

Is this possible with Mongo? If not then any suggestions!

When I turn off the Network adapter on the VM(Primary), the secondary doesn't seem to want to become the primary.

Is it possible to run 2 instance of Mongo, and then use the other instance as the 3 member of the replica.

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: I see that you are asking for recommendation without showing any effort from your side. Have you done your homework? Any research?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB always needs even number servers. in your case it should be like one primary one secondary and one arbiter. arbiter server instance is responsible for electing new server as primary when current primary goes down.